# Nameserver forwarding

Tags: nameservers

This probably will sound a strange question:

If I would like to do a Nameserver forwarding, how can I implement it?
Scenario
Domain is pointed at ns1 & ns2. 
Without changing the Registrar record for the ns1 & ns2, is it possible to point the domain records to be forwarded to ns3&n4 from the ns1&ns2?

What I am doing is creating NS type records at NS1 and it looks like it is not forwarding to the ns3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without declaring the NS3 and NS4 at the registry level, 
because of the Recursive Name Server.

Resolvers are querying step by step all the authoritative name servers from the domain hierarchy. That's where the recursive comes from. For a domain like `www.example.com.` the resolvers will ask:

1. "What are the NS for `.COM` ?" to `ROOT` Name Servers
2. "What are the NS for `example.com` ?" to `.COM` Name Servers
3. "What is the IP for `www.example.com` ?" to `example.com` Name Servers ?

That's why if the registry level don't know your NS3 and NS4 you will never receive any query on it.

I wrote an article on my personal blog introducing the domain name system if you are interested where I describe this in more detail: [What's a domain name and what's behind the scene](http://anouar.adlani.com/2011/12/what-is-a-domain-name-and-what-is-behind-the-scene.html#an-hierarchical-distributed-naming-system)

But what you could do is do delegate a subdomain to your NS3 and NS4, as described in this HOW-TO: [HOWTO - Delegate a Sub-domain (a.k.a. subzone)](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html).

Comment: Pease, update the link,readers run into error 404 - NOT FOUND error, it's better to add complete information to your answer or post links to a site that will be up and running forever..

Comment: Thank you for the updating the URL to your article, it's a good article and I like the video, its worth to watch and it's well written and explained.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful knowledge to solve what you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#DNAME_record

But be aware it's not exactly 99.999% safe.